# How to make subquery in django ORM

Tags: python, django

I have 2 tables: people and people_tag.

Every people has 3 tags in people_tag table.

I want to execute specific query.

Tables (I create this tables with help django ORM):

```
create table people (
    id serial primary key
);

create table people_tag (
    id serial primary key,
    people_id serial references people(id),
    tag text,
    threshold integer
);
```

Raw query example (that me need in result):

```
select people_id from (
select
    people_id,
    array_agg(tag) as tags from people_tag where threshold >= 40 group by people_id
) as t
where 'man' = ANY(tags) and ('tall' = ANY(tags) or 'short' = ANY(tags)) and 'thin' = ANY(tags);
```

I try that in django:

```
PeopleTag.objects.values_list('people_id').annotate(ArrayAgg('tag')).filter(threshold__gte=min_threshold)
```

And get:

```
SELECT "peopletag"."people_id", array_agg("peopletag"."tag") AS "tag__arrayagg" FROM "peopletag" WHERE "peopletag"."threshold" >= 70 GROUP BY "peopletag"."people_id";
```

How to make subquery for filter tags (tag__arrayagg)? I know how to make filtration(with .extra(where=...)), but can't make subquery.

In result me need people ID array.

Playground: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/97d788/16

Thank you.